# What is an alternative expression to "minority and women ran businesses"?

Tags: expressions

I'm looking for another way to say minority and women ran businesses

Comment: Well, I would say "minority and *woman-run* businesses".  And one can argue that there should be a dash after "minority".

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks 100%

Comment: I would say "businesses operated by minorities and women". Or it could be possible to find an all encompassing term for the group such as the socially repressed, or neglected social classes.